# Restar vidas Java Ahorcado

Tags: java

estoy desarrollando un Ahorcado en Java pero estoy trabado en restar las vidas.

```
for (int i = 0; i < palabra.length(); i++) {

            if (palabraoculta[i] == txt_letra.getText().charAt(0)) { 
                textfield[i].setText(txt_letra.getText());
                bandera = true;

            }

        }
        if (bandera != true) {

            vidas--;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, vidas);

        }
```

El for recorre la cantidad de letras que tiene la palabra y dentro la condicional verifica que si es igual que en esa/esas mismas posiciones ponga una letra. Ahora, la bandera es utilizada en el if del for para cuando la bandera sea true saltee la parte de restarle una vida, pero cuando el if de la bandera se cumple le restan las vidas pero cuando al momento de ingresar una letra que si esta en la palabra ya no resta mas las vidas. O sea para que se entienda mejor. Ingreso palabra = hola, yo le pongo letra f, la letra f no esta en hola y perfecto le resta una vida y asi sucesivamente hasta llegar a 0, pero si yo le ingreso una letra que si esta en la palabra ya despues no resta mas vidas, no llega mas a la condicional.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y en que momento pones la bandera en false? eso hay que hacerlo siempre justo antes del for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te falta volver a poner la variable bandera a false otra vez.

Solución:

```
for (int i = 0; i < palabra.length(); i++) {

        if (palabraoculta[i] == txt_letra.getText().charAt(0)) { 
            textfield[i].setText(txt_letra.getText());
            bandera = true;

        }

    }
    if (bandera != true) {

        vidas--;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, vidas);

    }
    bandera = false;
```

Comment: Es cierto, horas y horas solo porque no me di cuenta que tenia que regresar la variable a false. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @DeRosarioydeCentral recuerda aceptar la respuesta pulsando en el check verde de la izq para marcarla como aceptada. tanto el autor de la respuesta como tú ganais rep ;)